# Is MVC Routing Required?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is routing necessary, or can a site rely entirely on fully-formed URLs as requests, having only the default route?

Can one create a site while ramping up understanding of MVC, pushing learning about routes for later?

Comment: Routing, other than the default route, is optional and often not even required for simple sites. Note also, that routing is a part of asp infrastructure, MVC is one of many subsystems that make use of it.

Comment: In what case would you not want to route? Is it because your having problems passing parameters? Or something else? Yet @WiktorZychla is correct, you can pass fully built url's and the site will still navigate accordingly.

Comment: The one I am accountable to is balking at starting our next project as MVC with an attached unit testing project (instead of Web Forms). One allegation is that, not only would I have to ramp up my understanding of MVC, I have to learn routing, Entity Framework and LiNQ too. —— I told him that Entity Framework is not necessary (we can access SQL Server just as we always have), and without EF there would be no requirement to learn LiNQ.

Comment: Even with default routing, you are going to at least have to understand it a little bit.  I can't imagine making any site with more than 1 page without at least a cursory understanding.  I also can't imagine getting push back on moving to MVC over Web Forms.  That's like getting push back on moving to Chrome over Netscape Navigator, but perhaps I'm too opinionated.

Comment: He says "This application is pretty simple — it doesn't need the horsepower of ASP.NET MVC, and AJAX..." My insistence that it will be cleaner & easier to maintain falls on deaf ears. I pointed out that "it will make unit testing easy, and that it is almost impossible to unit test a web forms app" was met with "What do se need that for? We don't use unit testing on most of our [web forms] apps now." I pointed out that one of the presentations (just off the top of my head) is PERFECT for AJAX. (Of course, AJAX can be used in iether flavor of app.) *sigh*

Comment: I always pick small applications to try out new ideas and technologies.  That way, if they don't work out, starting over is reasonable.  Risk is much lower.  I would not start with a behemoth project.

Answer (score 1):

Routing in MVC is *required*, but Microsoft has provided a default route that is a reasonable choice in some situations (namely, intranet sites and for pages that are protected behind a login).

If your site is Internet facing, it would be better to customize routing to make the URLs more SEO-friendly. But, it is not absolutely required.

Comment: This application will have only 3 users and one administrator, here at our facility. It would make no difference, really, if it were entirely invisible to search engines.